# FluentValidation: Check if one of two fields are empty

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation, fluentvalidation

I have this **model**

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }  
}
```

I want to create a validation where either FirstName or LastName must be filled in by user.
I installed `FluentValidation` and created a **customvalidator class**

```
public class PersonValidator:AbstractValidator<Person>
{
    public PersonValidator()
    {
        RuleFor((person=>person.FirstName)//don't know how to check if one is empty
    }
}
```

To check just one field I could just do `RuleFor(person => person.FirstName).NotNull();`

But how do I check if one of them is null.

Also, is it possible, once validation is created via `fluentValidation`, use it on the client side to show error?

**Edit1**

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
    }
//creating validation
namespace WebApplication1.Models.CustomValidator
{
    public class PersonValidator:AbstractValidator<Person>
    {
        public PersonValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(m => m.FirstName).NotEmpty().When(m => string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.LastName)).WithMessage("*Either First Name or Last Name is required");
            RuleFor(m => m.LastName).NotEmpty().When(m => string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.FirstName)).WithMessage("*Either First Name or Last Name is required");
        }
    }

}
//model class
[Validator(typeof(PersonValidator))]
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        InterestList = new List<string>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    [RequiredIfEmpty("LastName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [RequiredIfEmpty("FirstName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public List<string> InterestList { get; set; } 
}
//view
@model WebApplication1.Models.Person

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddPerson","Person",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="label">First Name</div>
    <div class="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.FirstName)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.FirstName)</div>
    <br/>
    <div class="label">Last Name</div>
    <div class="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.LastName)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.LastName)</div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Submit</button>
}
```

Comment: What is the `RequiredIfEmpty` attribute?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can use [When/Unless](https://fluentvalidation.net/start#conditions) condition:

```
RuleFor(m => m.FirstName).NotEmpty().When(m => string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.LastName));
RuleFor(m => m.LastName).NotEmpty().When(m => string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.FirstName));
```

or

```
RuleFor(m => m.FirstName).NotEmpty().Unless(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.LastName));
RuleFor(m => m.LastName).NotEmpty().Unless(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.FirstName));
```

As for your second question, `FluentValidation` works with client-side validation, but not all rules are supported. [Here](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation) you can find validators, that are supported on the client-side:

1. NotNull/NotEmpty
2. Matches (regex)
3. InclusiveBetween (range)
4. CreditCard
5. Email
6. EqualTo (cross-property equality comparison)
7. Length

For rules that are not in the list you have to write your own `FluentValidationPropertyValidator` and implement `GetClientValidationRules`. You can find a few samples of this on the [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfluentvalidation%5D%20client%20side) by doing simple search.

Comment: I'm using `.NotEmpty` and `.When` so to show client side error what shoud i do? I'll edit my question so you can see what new i have added.

Comment: I just realized it doesn't work for when and unless. But still the fluentValidation is not working

Comment: Is there any way to do this but without having to populate both properties with the model state error?

Comment: not working for me, it is still complaining one field is missing while the other is populated

Answer (score 22):

Try this

```
RuleFor(person => person).Must(person => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(person.FirstName) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(person.LastName))
```

Comment: This fails when using ValidateAsync :(

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I got the following error: 
Property name could not be automatically determined for expression item => item. Please specify either a custom property name by calling 'WithName'.

Comment: @VladSchnakovszki what's item?

Comment: @FatShogun, it's the equivalent of person in your example.

Comment: @VladSchnakovszki afaik that error is produced when trying to validate something other than a property. Paste your relevant code and I'll see if I can provide you with a better answer.

Answer (score 6):

I did like this to check charges entered are same to previous one or not.
If charges are same as previous one than it'll give an error. This worked for me.

```
public class CasualMealChargeValidator : AbstractValidator<CasualMealCharge>
{
    public CasualMealChargeValidator(CasualMealCharge CMC)
    {
        //RuleFor(x => x.BankName).NotEmpty().When(pm => pm.PaymentMode == "Cheque").WithMessage("Enter Bank.");
        RuleFor(x => x).Must(x => x.DN != CMC.DN || x.BF != CMC.BF || x.LN != CMC.LN).WithMessage("Not Saved - Meal charges are same as current charges.").WithName("CMFor");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Finally, this worked for me. I wanted to validate three properties where at least one is required. It returns an error message only once.

```
RuleFor(p => p).Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
            .Must(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.FirstName))
            .When(p => p.Id == 0 && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.LastName)).WithMessage("At least one is required (Id, FirstName, LastName).")
            .Must(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.LastName))
            .When(p => p.Id == 0 && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.FirstName)).WithMessage("At least one is required (Id, FirstName, LastName).")
            .Must(p => p.Id != 0)
            .When(p => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.FirstName) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.LastName)).WithMessage("At least one is required (Id, FirstName, LastName).");
```

Comment: Surely you only need the first Must()/When()?

Comment: @sixeyes Are you asking or saying that I can improve?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but if all three values are null / 0, the first Must() would trigger. Why bother with the other two Must(). If you we're having different messages as @dummyDev answer it would make sense but your messages are all the same. I copied your code as it was what I was after but once I'd written my tests I found I didn't need the other Must(), hence my comment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that library, but if you just want to check those two properties for null, then you can use this:

```
RuleFor(person => person.FirstName ?? person.LastName).NotNull();
```

**EDIT** This doesn't work, because it throws an `InvalidOperationException`. Use Zabavsky's solution instead.

Comment: And here the OP really wants to use `NotEmpty()` as that checks for both `null` or and empty string.

Comment: The OP clearly say he's using `FluentValidation`. I don't know if I have outdated library, but this answer threw `System.InvalidOperationException` with error message: Property name could not be automatically determined for expression person => (person.FirstName ?? person.LastName). Please specify either a custom property name by calling 'WithName'.

Comment: @IronGeek You are right. I edited the answer. Use Zabavsky's solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

A nice rule-set to check if one of two fields are empty, as well as coming up with meaningful error codes is the following:

```
public CustomerSourceValidator()
    {
        CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;

        RuleFor(x => x)
            .NotNull().WithErrorCode("source_id_or_email_required")
            .When(source => source.Email == null && source.Id == null);

        RuleFor(x => x.Id)
            .NotNull().WithErrorCode("source_id_required")
            .Matches(CommonValidationRegex.CustomerIdRegexString).WithErrorCode("source_id_invalid")
            .When(source => source.Id != null);

        RuleFor(x => x.Email)
            .NotNull().WithErrorCode("source_email_required")
            .Matches(CommonValidationRegex.EmailRegexString).WithErrorCode("source_email_invalid")
            .When(source => source.Email != null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For people who have similar cases but with more properties (e.g. two fields out of four need to have a value), you can use something like this:

```
public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person>
{
    public PersonValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(person => person)
            .Must(MustHaveAtLeastTwoProperties)
            .WithMessage("Random validation message");
    }

    private bool MustHaveAtLeastTwoProperties(Person person)
    {
        return new[] { person.FirstName, person.LastName, person.Address1, person.Address2 } // Added Address1 and Address2 as new string properties
            .Count(prop => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(prop)) >= 2; // Set to how many properties you want to have a value
    }
}
```