# Validation rule for Allow Empty in EITHER ... OR ... case using fluent validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, nopcommerce, fluentvalidation

How to write a Validation rule for Allow Empty in EITHER Email OR in PhoneNumber

```
RuleFor(x => x.Email).NotEmpty().WithMessage(localizationService.GetResource("ContactUs.Email.Required"));
RuleFor(x => x.PhoneNumber).NotEmpty().WithMessage(localizationService.GetResource("Products.MakeAnOffer.PhoneNumber"));
```

Comment: So only Email or PhoneNumber can be empty, not both together?

Comment: Yes, that is True

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FluentValidation: Check if one of two fields are empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115179/fluentvalidation-check-if-one-of-two-fields-are-empty)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
    RuleFor(x => x.Email)
        .NotEmpty()
        .When(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PhoneNumber))//will run only if PhoneNumber is empty
        .WithMessage(localizationService.GetResource("ContactUs.Email.Required"));

    RuleFor(x => x.PhoneNumber)
        .NotEmpty().When(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Email))//will run only if Email is empty
        .WithMessage(localizationService.GetResource("Products.MakeAnOffer.PhoneNumber"));
```