# Require at least one collection to not be empty

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Using FluentValidation, I need to require that at least 1 collection out of 3 is not empty. This is the best way I can think to do this at the moment:

```cs
RuleFor(x => x).Must(x => x.Required.Any() || x.Ignored.Any() || x.Preferred.Any());
```

The type being validated is defined as:

```cs
public record ReleaseProfileData(
    string Name,
    [JsonProperty("trash_id")] string TrashId,
    bool IncludePreferredWhenRenaming,
    IReadOnlyCollection<TermData> Required,
    IReadOnlyCollection<TermData> Ignored,
    IReadOnlyCollection<PreferredTermData> Preferred
);
```

Is there a more "fluent" (idiomatic) way of expressing this type of rule? If so, could you provide an example?

Comment: There's an alternative using `Unless` [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21115780/1043380), but what you have seems good enough.

Comment: Does the `PreferredTermData` type inherit from `TermData`?

Comment: @gunr2171 It does not. It uses composition, though.